# ng-init not working when the ng-options list is changed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, initialization

The below select element loads and selects the first option on load of the control .
I change the positionAllowedList based on another dropdown. 
But ng-init does not select the first item.

```
<select ng-init="col.positionselected = col.positionAllowedList[0].value" ng-options="pos.value as pos.text for pos in col.positionAllowedList" ng-model="col.positionselected">
                                                </select>

$scope.ChangeBookingIso = function (col) {
                $.each(col.bookingIsoList, function (i, item) {                   
                        ....someLogic to change it is exactly the same structure the json list as before at the first time loaded.....
                        col.positionAllowedList = positionAllowedList;

                })

            }
```

Comment: You should not be using [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) (follow the link and read the first block) for that. ng-init expressions do not get evaluated during every digest cycle. use controller to set `col.positionselected `

Comment: Any particular reason , as I ideally expect ng-init to work as long as the ng-options list is valid , is it that the delay in between assigning cause ng-init to go for a toss ?

Comment: Actually there is no particular reason on why it should work this way, because that is not what it is designed for.

Comment: as the name suggests, ng-init is meant to define initial values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong directive for your usage. `ng-init` was never designed to initialize based on arbitrary(though can be misused) expressions on the view. [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) documentation itself says:

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

So general usage is with ng-repeat for aliasing its special properties like `$index`, `$first` etc so for example when you use nested `ng-repeat` within the child ng-repeat you can access parent ng-repeat's `$index` via alias set by `ng-init` without using `$parent.$index`, `$parent.$parent...$index` etc.

It is only one time initialization as well, if you look at the [source for ng-init](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInit.js#L59) it is pretty simple and straight forward.

```
var ngInitDirective = ngDirective({
  priority: 450,
  compile: function() {
    return {
      pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$eval(attrs.ngInit);
      }
    };
  }
});
```

*If you notice there is no `watch` created inorder to have the expression re-evaluated during every digest cycle.* So unsurprisingly it does not work as you intended it to work.

So just remove `ng-init` from `select` and instead set the property `col.positionselected` within the controller itself.

Comment: Thanks .... your answer made me debug a little further,  the reason i came with ng-init is because it was not working with setting ng-model , only now to realize that i was assigning 2 to it where i should assigned "2" ... duh

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad it will definite work during the first time, but not when some other event happens.