# Can you ng-init the value of ng-model based on other values on the scope?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, parseint, parsefloat, angularjs-ng-init

I'm trying to calculate 2 values that the user typed in and set that result as the ng-model for another value.  However I can't seem to get this code to work.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="a">
<input type="number" ng-model="b">
<input type="number" ng-init="c = a * b" ng-model="c">
```

I have also tried using parseFloat:

```
//in controller
$scope.parseFloat = parseFloat();

<input type="number" ng-init="c = (parseFloat(a) * parseFloat(b))" ng-model="c">
```

I CAN get the result I want as a label `{{a * b | number:2 | currency}}`, but not as an ng-model.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579223/ng-init-not-working-when-the-ng-options-list-is-changed#answer-30579456

Comment: ng-init can be used only with ng-repeat directive. you should use c as ng-model and update the value on on-change event

Comment: @fantarama to be precise, ng-init _can_ be used anywhere, but appropriate usage is for aliasing special properties of ng-repeat.

Comment: @PSL i agree, but since documentation strongly discourage usage outside ng-repeat scope I don't consider a valid solution using it for other purpose

Comment: @fantarama yup... i agree 101%, in fact i had mentioned it elaborately in the linked answer as well. I only commented when you said `can be used only`. :)

Comment: I should've pointed out that this IS inside of an ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-init` is only called once, when the node is intialized. You can try to use `ng-change` on the two inputs to set value of c

```
<input type="number" ng-model="a" ng-change='c=a*b'>
<input type="number" ng-model="b" ng-change='c=a*b'>
```

Comment: This would make sense to me but is still not working.  I'm actually getting a NAN error even though I have type="number".  Any ideas on that?